# C# How to create a database using sqlite code-first?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a .net console application and I'm trying to create a database using the code-first approach along with sqlite, but it doesn't get created. In all the tutorials that I found, the connection string was in the app.config file. But I don't have this file, so I chose the path that I found in the documentation.

Installed packages: EntityFramework. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

First, in the file manager console, I entered:
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration InitialCreate
then:
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database
the console displayed that everything was successful, but I do not see the created database

Here I defined the user model:

```
public class User
    {
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AccessLevel { get; set;}
    public string? Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // Banned, normal, muted.
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public User(string name, string password, string status)
    {
        Name = name;
        Password = password;
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

So I defined the context:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UsersContext() { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS");
    }
}
```

Comment: `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS");` - That won't fly. Either use SQLite **or** SQL Express. They are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: ConnectonStrings for SQLite: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/ If your migrations actually worked, I guess you have a DB in your local SQL Express Instance, but you'll never find a SQLite file.

Comment: `dotnet ef database update`?

Comment: Thanks for answers. The line worked: 
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=C:\GigaUsers.db"); 
but I was hoping the database would show up in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.